# python finding index of tag in string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

HTML

```
<div class="productDescriptionWrapper">
<p>A worm worth getting your hands dirty over. With over six feet of crawl space, Playhut&rsquo;s Wiggly Worm is a brightly colored and friendly play structure.
</p>
<ul>  
   <li>6ft of crawl through fun</li>    
   <li>18&rdquo; diameter for easy crawl through</li>    
   <li>Bright colorful design</li>    
   <li>Product Measures: 18&quot;&quot;Diam x 60&quot;&quot;L</li>    
   <li>Recommended Ages: 3 years &amp; up<br />    &nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Intended for Indoor Use</strong></p>
```

Code

```
def GetBullets(self, Soup):

    bulletList = []

    bullets = str(Soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'productDescriptionWrapper'}))

    bullets_re = re.compile('<li>(.*)</li>')

    bullets_pat = str(re.findall(bullets_re, bullets))

    index = bullets_pat.findall('</li>')

    print index
```

how to extract `p` tags and `li` tags? Thanks!

Comment: Be careful; these tags can be nested within each other, meaning an RE won't properly match up opening tags w/ their closing ones.  That's why you should use a parser like (presumably) BeautifulSoup.

Comment: You've used BeautifulSoup to find the div and then abandoned it and attempted to parse the string with a regex. I would suggest you stick with BeautifulSoup the whole way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the following:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """ <what you have above> """
>>> Soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> bullets = Soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'productDescriptionWrapper'})
>>> ptags = bullets[0].findAll('p')
>>> print ptags
[<p>A worm worth getting your hands dirty over. With over six feet of crawl space,      Playhut&rsquo;s Wiggly Worm is a brightly colored and friendly play structure.
</p>, <p><strong>Intended for Indoor Use</strong></p>]
>>> print ptags[0].text
A worm worth getting your hands dirty over. With over six feet of crawl space, Playhut&rsquo;s Wiggly Worm is a brightly colored and friendly play structure.
```

You can get at the contents of your li tags in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this.